# Is it possible to save data inside a custom popup?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, popup, save

just wondering. I want to make an app where you can add items in the MainActivity. After adding an item you go to the QuestionListActivity. This activity contains 8 questions. Clicking on a question opens a popup for that question with an EditText to answer and a save button. After closing the app and opening one of the saved items in the MainActivity, I want them to see the answer they saved inside each popup. (data must be saved internally)

Answer (score 0):

You can save Data in **Database** or save on **shared preference** in phone

Comment: But also in the internal storage right? But my question was if it possible to have 8 popups saved on the internal storage for each item that I add and view them when I open them again?

Comment: I think you are asking about saving data in external storage and get back.Yes it is possible in android

Comment: No, not external. It is like a note app where people only have to see their own saved data.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can set values in Shared Preference:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); 
 editor.putString("question_1", "Answer_1");
 editor.putString("question_2", "Answer_2");
 editor.putString("question_3", "Answer_3");// ... //
 editor.apply();
```

#### Retrieve data from Shared preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String answer1 = prefs.getString("question_1", ""); 
String answer2 = prefs.getString("question_2", ""); 
String answer3 = prefs.getString("question_3", "");//...//
}
```

Then you can set it to corresponding edit_texts

Comment: Are you sure this will work in my scenario? So each item they add in the MainActivity is one day of the month. And for each day they add they have to fill in the same questions. Can they still see all their saved data from all the other separate days?

Comment: So your need is to save data based on each day rite. In such a case use a Database like [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

Comment: Not particularly each day, just whenever they want to so more like a question form they can fill in as many times as they want and whenever they want. But they have to be able to view and change their older data

Comment: Then proceed with Realm Database